# Magento 2.3.X country dropdown issue in backend while customer address edit

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have selected Allow Countries as Saudi and one another as you can see in below screenshot
https://prnt.sc/qjyde9

the issue is that while edit customer record it's showing the different countries as selected from the dropdown in admin general settings.you can check the selected country list in above screenshot.
here is showing a different countries.
https://prnt.sc/qjyg3f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In This
>   `vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Form/Element/AbstractOptionsField.php`

Line no. 73

**From :-**

```
$config['options'] = array_values(array_replace_recursive($config['options'], $options));
```

**To :-**

```
$config['options'] = array_values(array_replace_recursive($options,$config['options']));
```

Comment: Thanks for helping it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**This solution is also worked for me**

Please open the below path file.

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/adminhtml/ui_component

open **customer_address_form.xml** and remove below code from line number.194

```
<formElements>
   <select>
       <settings>
           <options class="Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\Collection"/>
           </settings>
      </select>
 </formElements>
```

Remove the above code from the file and move this file to a local folder like below.

> app/code/Magento/Customer/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_address_form.xml

After remove that you will see your selected country into customer address edit in M2

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in Magento https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25218  Please go there and show support for it being fixed.