# Magento 2 : override abstarct class method

Tags: magento2, overrides, around-plugin

I want to override mone method **prepare** of class

> Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\AbstractOptionsField

I tried to do with preference but there is no effect

I also tried using plugin but it throws error

below is my plugin code

```
<type name="Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\AbstractOptionsField">
        <plugin name="aroundPrepare_override" type="Vendor\Custom\Plugin\AbstractOptionsField"/>
    </type>
```

> AbstractOptionsField file

```
<?php 
namespace Vendor\Custom\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;


class AbstractOptionsField extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\AbstractElement
{

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        $options = null,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->options = $options;
        parent::__construct($context, $components, $data);
    }

    public function aroundPrepare(
        \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\AbstractOptionsField $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) {

        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/customer123.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info("test");
   }

}
```

Can anyone help me what I missing.

> error

**Class Vendor\Custom\Plugin\AbstractOptionsField contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods**

Answer (score 1):

Your plugin should not extend **the original class**. I think just by removing the extend it should work.

Comment: I try to do this solution by override 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/300436/magento-2-3-x-country-dropdown-issue-in-backend-while-customer-address-edit